# java.io.FileNotFoundException on Mac

Tags: java, macos, filepath

```
final String FILE_PATH = "/Users/macbookair/Desktop/comp\\ sci\\ ia/TypingPractice/Player\\ records.rtf ";
```

This is my line of code to define the file path. It's giving me a "java.io.FileNotFoundException". The way I got this file path was by putting the file into the terminal and copying the path from there.

Is there something wrong I did to the file path?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must not escape the whitespace characters
2. You should remove the whitespace character at the end:

Code:

```
 false: /Users/.../comp\\ sci\\ ia/TypingPractice/Player\\ records.rtf ";
                       ^     ^                          ^             ^
 correct: /Users/.../comp sci ia/TypingPractice/Player records.rtf";
```